# Multiple Python GPIO buttons or Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have been experimenting with RPi.GPIO in python. And am stuck with something. When i try to add more than one button it only registers one being pressed. Does anybody know how to have multiple buttons being registered?
(These are physical, electrical push buttons not programmed ones)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think this question might be better suited to being asked over on [Raspberry PI](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

This is something I've been looking in to a bit recently, because I'm looking to hook up a custom arcade control via GPIO rather than USB.

To answer your question:

According to [this paper](http://magikh0e.ihtb.org/pubPapers/Raspberry_PI-LCD-Buttons.html) you would hook each button up like this:

[Picture of the button wiring http://uk.omg.li/P0oo/Image%202013.05.16%2010%3A17%3A30.jpeg](http://uk.omg.li/P0oo/Image%202013.05.16%2010%3A17%3A30.jpeg)

With a GPIO pin corresponding to each button, so:

1. Pin 1 from the button connects to 3.3V on the breadboard with a 10k resistor
2. Pin 1 from the button connects to GPIO # corelating to the buttons function.
3. Pin 2 from the button connects to -/Ground on the breadboard.

The paper goes on to detail high/low pull states for the buttons, and provides some example Python code to make it all work.

I hope that helps!